# What is the difference between have and have got

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> I have a gift for you
>
> I have got a gift for you

Which one is correct?
They say that *have* and *have got* are interchangeable but I don't think this works here because ***I have got*** would mean ***I have received (a gift for you)*** which doesn't sound right as far as I think

Comment: It might help you to know that ***I have got*** can just as easily be paraphrased as ***I have obtained*** or ***I am in possession of***, which should make more sense in *I have got a gift for you.* Whether or not ***got*** is included alongside ***have*** would rarely make any difference to the meaning there. In some contexts, *I **got** a gift for you* (with no ***have***) might be understood as focusing more on *the act of obtaining the gift* (in the past) rather than the fact of having it available to give to you (in the present), but really that's just splitting hairs.

Comment: The linked duplicate does a generally good job of covering this but misses one small aspect because the focus of that question was "got" vs. "have got" and this one is "have" vs. "have got".  In this question, the object of "have" is a noun.  But instead of possession, "have" can also mean "must" when used with a verb.  I must go = I have to go.  In that usage, "got" can add emphasis.  "I have **got** to go" = I **really** must go.  "Got" can also add emphasis for possession.  "I have an itch" vs. "Have I got an itch!"

Answer (score 0):

The answer differs a bit between UK and American English.

In American English, the past participle of 'got' is 'gotten', so when you say "'I have got' would mean 'I have received'", that's not quite the case in America. You would need to say 'I have *gotten*' to mean 'I have received'. Instead, in American English, 'have got' is an idiom that is nearly identical in meaning to 'have'. In fact, interestingly, it matches 'have' in both the sense of 'to possess' and 'to be obligated to'. So 'I have to run' and 'I've got to run' also mean the same thing.

In the UK, as I understand it, 'got' is the past particle form of 'got', so 'I have got' does indeed mean 'I have received', which is not quite the same thing as saying 'I have'